# Repeated character in pair using regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list of numbers, and using regex that look like this `(\d)(?=\d*\1)`
 
Example list of numbers:

> 1234
>   5678
>   5565
>   5566
>   5567
>   5656
>   1212

Current Output using the expression:

> 5565
>   5566
>   5567
>   5656
>   1212

However, I want to extract list of numbers that are in 2 pairs in 4 numbers no matter what the arrangement is. For example: **1122, 1212, 2211, 2121, 1221, 2112**

Example of Desired Output: (where 5565, 5567 is false)

> 5566
>   5656
>   1212

I am not familiar with regex, need some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your numbers are always 4 digits you can do something like this

```
(?:(\d)(\d)\1\2)|(?:(\d)\3(\d)\4)|(?:(\d)(\d)\6\5)
```

So, if you have four digit numbers you can only have two different digits in each number. With `\1` you can reference the first digit, with `\2` the second, etc. This regex matches the three possible distributions: `abab`, `abba` and `aabb`.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/cP4nI5/2

Comment: This is nice :) Solves OP's problem.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than `Regex`, if you want plain `C#` code, this will do

```
int number = 1212;
var isDoublePair = number.ToString()
                    .ToCharArray()
                    .GroupBy(c => c)
                    .Select(grp => grp.Count())
                    .All(count => count == 2);
```

As commented by w.b, this can be shortened to

```
var isDoublePair = number.ToString()
                     .GroupBy(c => c)
                     .All(g => g.Count() == 2);
```

Comment: You don't need `ToCharArray` and `Select` here, it can be `number.ToString().GroupBy(c => c).All(g => g.Count() == 2)`

Comment: thanks, this work as well. angela provide the regex solution below too.

Comment: @erkeni yes. You can use Angela's Regex directly as you wanted.